# Custom unmarshall to a type than input out different type

Tags: go, unmarshalling

I'm learning Go and I have a question:

I have an `Info` type that is defined like that:

```
type Info struct {
    ID          ID     `json:"id,omitempty"`
    DisplayName string `json:"display_name,omitempty"`
}
```

I made a custom `UnmarshallJSON` function to unmarshall this struct because as an input I have either:

- An `[]interface{}`  with at position [0] an int and [1] a string
- A `boolean` always equals to `false` meaning that the field is `null`

I want that when the input is `false`, the Info is nil.

Here's the `UnmarshallJSON` function

```
func (i *Info) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
var v []interface{}
if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &v); err != nil {
    var v bool
    if err = json.Unmarshal(data, &v); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
i.ID = ID(v[0].(float64))
i.DisplayName = v[1].(string)
return nil
}
```

It's ugly, and I would like to know if there's a better option.
Thank you very much.

Comment: It looks fine and does the job. Note however you can't set the struct pointer to `nil`. When your `UnmarshalJSON()` is called, `i` will not be `nil`. You may set `i` to `nil` but that is just a local variable, you can't `nil` the original pointer passed as the receiver.

Comment: Yeah I just saw that, I edited it

Comment: why are you doing this `i.ID = ID(v[0].(float64))` instead of `i.ID = v[0].(int)` ? What id ID type means?

Comment: ID is an int but when I unmarshall v[0], it tells me that it is a float64. The fact is I know it is an int because it's an ID in a database

Comment: If the `ID` field is of type `int`, it should be `i.ID = int(v[0].(float64))`

Comment: Sorry the ID field is of type ID, which is an int.

Comment: "It's ugly" No, it is not. Your API is ugly and this reflects in code.

Comment: Thankfully it's not mine haha. I'm using a library that make request to an Odoo server. I don't know if the "ugly API" comes from the library (Unmarshalling not well) or the Odoo XMLRPC response. If it comes from the library, I can touch the code so I'll not having this problem again

Comment: It certainly is an ugly API. The reason you get a float64 is because you "fully" unmarshaled the data into a []interface{}, go has to put it in something and a float64 has the largest scope. If instead you "partially" unmarshal into a []json.RawMessage, it will not unmarshal the elements, meaning you can do it later into your desired types. I've added an answer showing how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fist you should be more defensive about unexpected types and length to avoid a panic. Then you can unmarshal into a `[]json.RawMessage` to defer unmarshaling of the elements until you are ready. Finally you should guard against your invalid `true`.

Here is my best effort, please others feel free to edit ([here](https://play.golang.org/p/XFc510m0vDN) is a playground):

```
func (i *Info) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var raw interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &raw); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    switch r := raw.(type) {
    case []interface{}:
    case bool:
        if r {
            return errors.New("unexpected true, must be array or false")
        }
        return nil
    default:
        return fmt.Errorf("unexpected type %T, must be array or false", r)
    }

    var v []json.RawMessage
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &v); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if len(v) != 2 {
        return fmt.Errorf("unexpected length %d, must be 2", len(v))
    }

    if err := json.Unmarshal(v[0], &i.ID); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if err := json.Unmarshal(v[1], &i.DisplayName); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm learning something thanks to you :)